# Adding backwards compatibility for iOS 7 failing due to framework

Tags: ios, import, frameworks, ios8

I have an app that utilizes iOS 8's new touch ID using:

```
#import "LocalAuthentication/LocalAuthentication.h"
```

But at startup on an iOS 7, the app crashes. I do not call the touch ID program if it is not running on iOS 8+. The log tells me it is from importing the framework, but I have the framework set to optional, so it should work unless I missed a step... Why would the log tell me otherwise?

[image]

Comment: Where is the optional for importing your framework?

Comment: I do it in the build phases section under "link with library"

Comment: Please post a screenshot or something.

Comment: Well I'm assuming if you are trying to `#import` a library that wasn't linked it's going to cause a problem...

Comment: "Link Binary With Libraries (0 Items)"... **0 Items**. Please post your crash log.

Comment: That was a picture of the location. My actual app has over 12 instead of 0.

Comment: I've seen this problem if you use a global variable defined in the library - Apple likes to declare items as "extern const" at times. The easiest fix is to duplicate the variable within your code if this is the case.

Comment: Sorry @EricS, but I am a bit confused by that. Can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: In one of the library headers you may something like "extern const CLLocationAccuracy kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;". If you use this constant and it's not available on a particular version of iOS, you'll get an error. The fix is to duplicate the value within your own code under a different name.

Comment: Giving an exact error message, exact log, stack trace for the crash, etc. would make it easier for people to help you.